# ExtJS - How to minimize the roweditor's height?

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic, extjs6.2

As I attached the screenshot, I need to minimize the height of `roweditor` of `grid`.

Here is the configuration of `rowediting` plugin:

```
ptype           : 'rowediting',
clicksToMoveEditor: 1,
saveBtnText     : 'Kaydet',
cancelBtnText   : 'İptal',
errorsText      : 'Hata',
errorSummary    : false,
autoCancel      : false
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add **beforeedit** listener to assign custom height for editor as well as elements within editor as follows:

```
    listeners: {
        beforeedit: function (plugin) {
            //set height of editor
            plugin.editor.setHeight(200);
            // set height of each element within editor
            plugin.editor.items.each(function (b) {
                b.setHeight(100);
            })
        }
    },
```

Working fiddle example : https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/28d5